# .each() > $(this).find().eq().html() is null

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why don't work?

```
var str;

$('table tr').each(function() {
    str = $(this).find('td').eq(6).html().trim().substring(10, 20);
    $(this).find('td').eq(6).text(str);
});
```

Need write in all 6th  trim+substring+another_string_action with same value.

Firebug write error: **$(this).find("td").eq(6).html() is null**

Comment: Are you sure there is a 6th cell in every row?

Comment: Can you paste your HTML (or a snippet) in here?

Comment: @Nick - `.eq(6)` actually would (as you know) require a 7th column in each row.

Comment: @patrick - That's my 120th off-by-one error today, or maybe 121st :(

Comment: @Nick - Just imagine a place *where all the women are strong, all the men are good-looking, all the children are above average, and there are no 0 based indexes*.

Comment: I mean 7th, it's mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things.

First, remember that not all browsers have a native `.trim()` function. Safer to use jQuery's `$.trim()`.

- http://api.jquery.com/jquery.trim/

Second, remember that `.eq()` takes a `0` based index, so if you want the sixth `<td>` column, pass `5`. Right now you're asking for the seventh `<td>`.

```
var str;

$('table tr').each(function() { 
    var $td = $(this).find('td').eq(5); // Get sixth <td> in the row
    str = $.trim( $td.html() ).substring(10, 20);
    $td.text(str);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid repeating the lookup of the table cell anyway:

```
$('table tr').each(function() {
  var cell = $(this).find('td').eq(6);
  if (cell.length) {
    cell.text(cell.html().trim().substring(10, 20));
  }
});
```

It might also be good to check the original string to make sure it's as long as the code expects. Finally, you *get* the contents with `.html()` but then you *set* with `.text()`.  Is that really what you want?